# Number of generators in $(\mathbb{Z}_m^*, \cdot_m)$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

The group $(\mathbb{Z}_m^*, \cdot_m)$ is the group with elements
$$ \{ a \in \{0, 1, ..., m-1\}  \mid \gcd(a, m) = 1  \} $$
and
$\cdot_m$ is the relation $a\cdot_m b = a \cdot b \mod m$.

How many generators are in the group $(\mathbb{Z}_{100}^*, \cdot_{100})$?

Given that I know that $(\mathbb{Z}_{25}^*, \cdot_{25})$ is cyclic and a subgroup of $(\mathbb{Z}_{100}^*, \cdot_{100})$, I'd say the group  $(\mathbb{Z}_{100}^*, \cdot_{100})$ is also cyclic and so must have $\phi(100)$ generators with $\phi(100)$ the [Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) $\phi$ function, so there should be $40$ generators.

Comment: How can you tell that it has only one generator?

Comment: The answer below, which you agreed with apparently, says that there are none.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $gcd(x,100)=1$ implies 
$$x^{20} \equiv 1 \pmod{25} \\
x^{20} \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$$

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem you then get 
$$x^{20}\equiv 1 \pmod{100}$$

Since your group has 40 elements, the group cannot be generated by a single element.

Comment: I understand that the group is not cyclic because $100$ is not $2*prime^r$, with prime > 2 and $r$ >=1 .

Comment: N. S. showed a simpler, elementary way to see it's not cyclic. If you know it's not cyclic, why are you asking how many generators it has?

Comment: Is this correct: a non-cyclic group implies that there is no generator?

Comment: That's right.   If the group is generated by a single element,   then, by definition,  it's cyclic.

Answer (score 2):

Since $100$ is the product of the mutually prime numbers $25$ and $4$, one would expect that $\Bbb Z_{100}^*$ would have the structure of $\Bbb Z_{25}^*\oplus\Bbb Z_4^*$, thus isomorphic to the (additive) group $\Bbb Z_{20}\oplus\Bbb Z_2$.

One may take the generator of $\Bbb Z_{25}^*$ to be $17$, of $\Bbb Z_4^*$ to be $3$. The two separate generators should be $\equiv17\pmod{25}$ and $\equiv1\pmod4$ for the one; and $\equiv1\pmod{25}$ and $\equiv3\pmod4$ for the other. Using Chinese Remainder Theorem, that would be $17$ and $51$ for the two generators.

Answer (score 0):

Along the same lines as @Lubin, the group of units functor respects direct products.   Thus we can expect $\Bbb Z_{100}^*\cong(\Bbb Z_{25}\times\Bbb Z_4)^*\cong\Bbb Z_{25}^*\times\Bbb Z_4^*\cong\Bbb Z_{20}\times\Bbb Z_2$, and the latter is not cyclic.

Then looking at @N. S.'s answer,  note that the order of an element $(a,b)\in\Bbb Z_{20}\times \Bbb Z_2$ will divide $\operatorname {lcm}(2,20)=20$.